# How do we calculate the adjustment factor for hyperbolic secant pulse for calculation of peak power in ultrashort laser pulses?

Tags: laser

In the formula for peak power it is equal to total energy divided by FWHM pulse width multiplied by an adjustment factor 'a' the value of which depends on the shape of the pulse.
For hyperbolic secant pulse the value is 0.88. How do we get this?

Comment: I have to say: that's an awesome question title. No idea what it means, though.

Comment: No answers yet. You might try expanding the question: adding some explanations of what you do know, expanding acronyms, etc.